# Launch browser from c# and fill in username and password

Tags: c#, browser, authentication, httpwebrequest

I was wondering if anyone knows how to launch a normal browser session and enter username and password details from c# code - perhaps using a webrequest?

nb the username and password is the popup screen not an embedded username and password tag.

Comment: Do you mean fill username/password inputs from a c# code? is this web site yours or is it third-party?

Answer (score 1):

Though this can be done through a web request, there are pre-built tools which support this, like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).  It even comes with a FireFox plugin, which records your actions on a site (such as logging in) and exports the C# code needed to automate the command.

It used primarily as a test generation framework, but you could easily record the login, then edit the generated C# code to use a dynamic user name and password.

What makes this framework really nice is that it handles the html parsing for you.  Additionally, it can optionally use a dedicated server or servers to perform the tests if you'll need to do a whole lot of queries.